# Javascript Date for the next 2 days

Tags: javascript, date

I use this code to show the next 2 days

```
var mydate= new Date();
mydate.setDate(mydate.getDate()+2)
document.write("Tomorrow Date :" +mydate.getDate()+"/"+(mydate.getMonth()+1)+"/"+mydate.getFullYear());
```

and it gives me a correct date, but I want it to have this format example: Jan-01-2012.

Can anyone help me on this?  I tried using this string `mydate.format('mmm,d,y');` and it returns none.

Thanks in adnvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to format a `Date` with native javascript API.

The only possible output with native API is the combination of `d`, `dd`, `ddd`, `M`, `MM`, `MMM`, `y`, `yy`, and `yyyy` by using `toString()` and `get*()` methods and regular expression.

So the better solution is to use a third party library, like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I used the moment.js. and it gives me a correct answer. the only problem is it shows this extra string 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time) I want to removed it and just simply Wed Nov 28 2012. here is my current code.

`var today = new Date();`
`var d = today.getDate();`
`var m = today.getMonth();`
`var y = today.getFullYear();`
`var NextDate= new Date(y, m, d+2);`
`var Ndate=moment(NextDate.getMonth()+1+"/"+NextDate.getDate()+"/"+y);`

Comment: @tmv1845331 `moment().add('days', 2).format('MMM-DD-YYYY')` and ***read*** the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `toLocaleString()` which converts the results of a `Date()` to a string respecting locale conventions, [as described here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp).

If you *really* need something specific you'll need to build an array as shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp).